# Help parsing the Midrashim of ר׳ חנינא from בר׳ ל״ג ב׳

Tags: talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot

Can anyone offer help parsing the Midrashim of ר׳ חנינא from [בר׳ ל״ג ב](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=33b&format=pdf)?

He seems to quote himself in third person a couple of times:
״ואמר ר׳ חנינא הכל...והא אמר ר׳ חנינא משום ר׳ שמעון בן יוחי אין לו...דאמר ר׳ חנינא משל...״
Any insights would be appreciated.

---

This question is part of the Daf Yomi Challenge.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. I see three (well, 4 but I think you are referring to the latter 3) statements of his on the page. Where do you see him quoting himself?

Comment: It seems to be "statement...but different statement...but statement..." Unless it's the Gemara raising the objections?

Comment: "Unless..": That's how I read it. Note the switch from Hebrew to Aramaic.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's it. Thanks. Too localized?

Comment: It's not any worse than some of the other random translations and source references that we get. I can write up an official answer now. (ba, everything ok?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full text of the relevant piece follows. I have put statements of R Chanina in bold, and statements of the gemara-narrator/stama in italics.

*אמר רבי חנינא* **הכל בידי שמים חוץ מיראת שמים שנאמר ועתה ישראל מה ה' אלהיך שואל מעמך כי אם ליראה** *אטו יראת שמים מילתא זוטרתא היא והא"ר חנינא משום ר' שמעון בן יוחי* **אין לו להקב"ה בבית גנזיו אלא אוצר של יראת שמים שנאמר יראת ה' היא אוצרו** *אין לגבי משה מילתא זוטרתא היא דאמר ר' חנינא* **משל לאדם שמבקשים ממנו כלי גדול ויש לו דומה עליו ככלי קטן קטן ואין לו דומה עליו ככלי גדול:**

In other words, the structure is: statement by R Chanina; contradictory statement of R Chanina; a third statement of R Chanina which resolves the contradiction. All statements are being quoted directly by the gemara, including all the "flow-words" which indicate that the contradiction exists and how it is resolved. Note how all the bold text is in Hebrew and the italicized text is in Aramaic: the former are the words of R Chanina, and the latter are the words of the Gemara. There are no nested statements.

This understanding of the text is backed up by the Hebrewbooks translation of the page in [Hebrew](http://hebrewbooks.org/shastrans.aspx?msid=1&daf=33&lang=he) and in [English](http://hebrewbooks.org/shastrans.aspx?msid=1&daf=33&lang=en).

Comment: Thanks! It seems pretty obvious now. I guess I was getting tired and was losing focus. [Fortunately, nobody hit me with a hammer!](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18911/5)